# PayPal SDK Array of products return an error

Tags: php, api, paypal

I'm learning PayPal SDK and it worked perfectly, when I was firstly working with one product. Now I have to work with an array of products. Thay's the code

```
$paypal = new ApiContext(
        new OAuthTokenCredential(
            '...',
            '...'
        )
    );

    $payer = new Payer();
    $payer->setPaymentMethod('paypal');

    $shipping = 2;
    $totalPriceWithShipping = 0;
    $totalPriceWithoutShipping = 0;


    $items = [];

    foreach(Controller::getData('productsInCart') as $product)
    {
        $totalPriceWithShipping += ($product->price + $shipping);
        $totalPriceWithoutShipping += $product->price;

        $item = new Item();

        $item->setName($product->name)
            ->setPrice($product->price)
            ->setCurrency('USD')
            ->setQuantity(1);

        $items[] = $item;
    }

    $itemList = new ItemList();
    $itemList->setItems($items);

    $details = new Details();
    $details->setShipping($shipping)
            ->setSubtotal($totalPriceWithoutShipping);


    $amount = new Amount();
    $amount->setCurrency('USD')
        ->setTotal($totalPriceWithShipping)
        ->setDetails($details);



    $transaction = new Transaction();
    $transaction->setItemList($itemList)
                ->setAmount($amount)
                ->setDescription('Your Order from Online Shop')
                ->setInvoiceNumber(uniqid());

    $redirectUrls = new RedirectUrls();
    $redirectUrls->setReturnUrl('...')
                ->setCancelUrl('...');

    $payment = new Payment();
    $payment->setIntent('sale')
            ->setPayer($payer)
            ->setRedirectUrls($redirectUrls)
            ->setTransactions([$transaction]);

    try {
        $payment->create($paypal);
    }
    catch(Exception $e) {
        die($e->getTrace());
    }

   die($payment->getApprovalLink());
```

But I am somehow getting this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PayPal\Exception\PayPalConnectionException' with message 'Got Http response code 400 when accessing https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment.' in C:\dev\htdocs\Shop\vendor\paypal\rest-api-sdk-php\lib\PayPal\Core\PayPalHttpConnection.php:180 Stack trace: #0 C:\dev\htdocs\Shop\vendor\paypal\rest-api-sdk-php\lib\PayPal\Transport\PayPalRestCall.php(74): PayPal\Core\PayPalHttpConnection->execute('{"intent":"sale...') #1 C:\dev\htdocs\Shop\vendor\paypal\rest-api-sdk-php\lib\PayPal\Common\PayPalResourceModel.php(102): PayPal\Transport\PayPalRestCall->execute(Array, '/v1/payments/pa...', 'POST', '{"intent":"sale...', NULL) #2 C:\dev\htdocs\Shop\vendor\paypal\rest-api-sdk-php\lib\PayPal\Api\Payment.php(422): PayPal\Common\PayPalResourceModel::executeCall('/v1/payments/pa...', 'POST', '{"intent":"sale...', NULL, Object(PayPal\Rest\ApiContext), NULL) #3 C:\dev\htdocs\Shop\app\controllers\CartController.php(183): PayPal\Api\Payment->create(Object(PayPal\Rest\ApiContext)) #4 [internal functio in C:\dev\htdocs\Shop\vendor\paypal\rest-api-sdk-php\lib\PayPal\Core\PayPalHttpConnection.php on line 180

and just so you can take a look at **$items** array

[$items array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iue7V.jpg)

Comment: So there is problem with shipping. If shipping equals 0 it works.

Answer (score 0):

Getting 400 exception means, paypal is returning with some exception. To get more details on that exception. You need to catch that uncaught exception `PayPal\Exception\PayPalConnectionException` to get more details.

[This page should](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/wiki/exception-%27PayPal%5CException%5CPayPalConnectionException%27-with-message-%27Got-Http-response-code-400-when-accessing) help you give some idea. Below is the sample code to catch that exception:

```
try {
    $payment->create($apiContext);
} catch (PayPal\Exception\PayPalConnectionException $ex) {
    echo $ex->getCode(); // Prints the Error Code
    echo $ex->getData(); // Prints the detailed error message 
    die($ex);
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    die($ex);
}
```

Comment: I tried this already and commented, that there is a problem with shipping. It displays this: **{"name":"VALIDATION_ERROR","details":[{"field":"transactions[0].amount","issue":"Transaction amount details (subtotal, tax, shipping) must add up to specified amount total"}],"message":"Invalid request - see details","information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#VALIDATION_ERROR","debug_id":"f75886db2f541"}**

Comment: That explains your flaw in the logic for getting priceWithShipping and withoutShipping. In your case, you are adding shipping per item. However, you are adding shipping ($2) only to paypal. This makes the mismatch.

Comment: Thanks. Works fine now :)